# Javascript not showing notification from GET springboot rest api

Tags: javascript, java, spring-boot

I am totally new to javascript . I just want to show a notification using `notify.js` when a button is clicked.

Following is my `RestController` code:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/checkCurrentBranch" , method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String checkCurrectGitBranch(Model model, HttpServletResponse response) {

        String branchName = "";
        GitInfo gitInfo = new GitInfo();
        JsonFactory factory = new JsonFactory();
        String json = apiService.readGitProperties();
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper(factory);
        JsonNode rootNode;
        try {
            rootNode = mapper.readTree(json);

            Iterator<Map.Entry<String, JsonNode>> fieldsIterator = rootNode.fields();
            while (fieldsIterator.hasNext()) {
                Map.Entry<String, JsonNode> field = fieldsIterator.next();
                if (field.getKey().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("git.branch")) {
                    branchName = field.getValue().toString();
                    adminAppLogger.info("Current Branch name :: "+branchName);
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            adminAppLogger.error("Error while getting current Git branch :" + e);
            branchName = "Error while fetching branch name";
        }
        model.addAttribute("res", branchName);
        return branchName;
    }
```

Following is my js code:

```
$('#gitBranch').click(function(res) {

    /* <![CDATA[ */
    var path = /* [[@{/}]] */'checkCurrentBranch';
    /* ]]> */
        $.notify(res, "info");
        console.log(res);

});
```

I think I am missing some points but I am stuck. Any suggestions?

I tried using axios following is my js:

```
$('#gitBranch').click(function(res) {

        /* <![CDATA[ */
        var path = /* [[@{/}]] */'checkCurrentBranch';
        /* ]]> */

        axios({
              method:'get',
              url:path,
              responseType:'json'
            })
              .then(function (response) {
                console.log(response)
                $.notify(data,"info")

              });
    });
```

Following response I get on  brwoser console. Now I just want that data field to be shown as notification :

```
{data: "qc_mediaworker_details", status: 200, statusText: "", headers: {…}, config: {…}, …}
config
:
{adapter: ƒ, transformRequest: {…}, transformResponse: {…}, timeout: 0, xsrfCookieName: "XSRF-TOKEN", …}
data
:
"qc_mediaworker_details"
headers
:
{pragma: "no-cache", date: "Sun, 04 Nov 2018 05:59:32 GMT", x-content-type-options: "nosniff", x-frame-options: "DENY", content-type: "application/json;charset=UTF-8", …}
request
:
XMLHttpRequest {onreadystatechange: ƒ, readyState: 4, timeout: 0, withCredentials: false, upload: XMLHttpRequestUpload, …}
status
:
200
statusText
:
""
__proto__
:
Object
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have anywhere http request.
I recommend you using [axios](https://github.com/axios/axios) (because it's simple)
Sample code:

```
axios.get('host:port/checkCurrentBranch')
.then(response => {
    // do what you want to do
})
.catch(error => {
    // do something if an error occurs
})
```

Comment: Yeah ,I have tried it but still unable to show notification using notify.js.

Comment: response object contains key 'data' you just have get it like:
response.data

Answer (score 2):

You need to properly use data key in axios response block.

```
axios({
          method:'get',
          url:path,
          responseType:'json'
        })
          .then(function (response) {
            console.log(response)
            $.notify(response.data,"info")

          });
```

In above code, I replaced data by response.data
, because according your give code, data is not declared, that means its undefined. So if you mean data to that data which you get in axios response, then you need to access data by `$.notify(response.data,"info")` instead of `$.notify(data,"info")`